# How to affect only directories with Move-Item in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, batch, move

I am flattening a directory and I want to move items that are directories, but leave files untouched.

Unfortunately, there is no distinct pattern that can be wildcard matched between the directories and the files. I want to know if it is possible to tell `Move-Item` to only examine directories (or on the flip side files).

Examining the output of `Get-Help -Name Move-Item` this does not seem to be directly possible (i.e. by a parameter like `-ItemType`). Of the top of my head it might be possible to do this using a hack, e.g. `-Exclude *.*`, but I want a more robust solution. Thanks.

Comment: Could [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68326645/21885072) be helpful?

Comment: Possibly. I had wanted a simple one liner, but I guess a `ForEach` loop with a condition would achieve what I was after. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't look at just the function itself, remember PowerShell has powerful [piping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines?view=powershell-7.3) capability. To move only directories, filter them first, then pipe into `Move-Item`, e.g.:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Some\Dir -Directory | Move-Item -Destination C:\Other\Dir
```

[`-Directory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3#-directory) switch of [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3) means that only folder children will be found.

Comment: Great one liner, piping was the last thing on my mind.

Comment: Whenever you are at a loss, always see if piping will come to your rescue.  Remember, pipes carry objects.